# How to set formatting for a particular Word VBA comment

Tags: vba, ms-word, comments

I want to use VBA to format one particular Word Comment. (So it seems Comment Text and Balloon Text styles wouldn't help, since they would affect all comments.)

I have a variable referring to the Comment. Here is a code extract:

```
  Dim myComment as Object

  Set myComment = ActiveDocument.Range.Comments.Add (.Duplicate, "The wisest was Sir Thomas Tom.")
  myComment.Author = "Mickey Mouse"
  myComment.Initial = "MM"
```

In the web documentation I don't see any properties listed for the Comment Object that would help format the body of a comment. But on the other hand, the Comment Object does seem to have properties 'Author' and 'Initial', since the above code snippet sets them successfully. I haven't seen either of these in any official properties list, so maybe there are others I don't know about? (Author and Initial were copied from some sample code on the web.)

I'll be grateful for any pointers on how to format various aspects of a comment with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

One addresses comment ranges in exactly the same way as ranges elsewhere in the document when they're not in the document body. For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim myComment As Comment, Rng As Range
With ActiveDocument
  Set myComment = .Comments.Add(Selection.Range, "The wisest was Sir Thomas Tom.")
  With myComment
    .Author = "Mickey Mouse"
    .Initial = "MM"
    Set Rng = .Range
    With Rng
      .Start = .Words(4).Start
      .Font.Bold = True
    End With
  End With
End With
End Sub
```